# Create Bootstrap dropdown from input[type="text"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using this example i create dropdown [Bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

But for my case it will be better to have some input[type="text"] instead of button. Because i want to show what i choose in dropdown?

Is there any solution?

First what come to my head to add js-click which will change text of button.

Comment: So you want it to work exactly like a `<select>` element?

Comment: Can you picture what you have in mind?

Comment: @Juhana, yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a dropdown that behaves like an html select element you can look here

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: yes, it can be good solution. And as i see there is also option to select all

Answer (score 0):

Better take a look at jQueryUI autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I dont think bootstrap provide anything like this so far.